# Galleria software - Could not extract a stage height from the CSS

Tags: galleria

I'm experiencing an error - *Could not extract a stage height from the CSS: Traced height 0px* - when I refresh a page with a Galleria gallery in both IE8 and Firefox 6.0.2.  I've made these changes:

1) To the html by changing this tag -

```
 !DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 //EN"
```

2) Added the height attribute to the

```
.galleria-stage {height: 467px;}
```

3) Matched the following tags in the head section -

```
 link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="galleria/themes/classic/galleria.classic.css"
 script type="text/javascript" src="js/galleria-1.2.5.min.js"
 script type="text/javascript" src="galleria/themes/classic/galleria.classic.min.js"
```

I continue to experience this error.  Please help!  (I've removed less than and greater than symbols in this posting but they are included in my code).

Thanks,

Rick R.

Answer (score 4):

According to the script author this problem has been fixed in the latest beta: https://github.com/aino/galleria/blob/master/src/galleria.js

Answer (score 3):

I was experiencing the same issue and added the height attribute to the galleria.classic.css as well as implemented the file that "Tell me Where is Gandalf" recommended and my error went away. I was going to +1 his but my reputation isn't high enough ;)

Answer (score 3):

not cool solution is to add at the end on galleria styling

```
.galleria-errors{display: none;}
```

its just to ignore error message

Answer (score 3):

actually, the trick is to add the height setting in-page, and leave the rest of the settings like they are in the example
(at least for me in chrome 18.0.1025.168 m)

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="galleria/galleria-1.2.7.min.js"></script>
        <style>
            #galleria{height:467px}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="galleria">
            <img src="photos/photo1.jpg">
            <img src="photos/photo2.jpg">
            <img src="photos/photo3.jpg">
        </div>
        <script>
            Galleria.loadTheme('galleria/themes/classic/galleria.classic.min.js');
            Galleria.run('#galleria');
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with version 1.2.5 and fixed it by placing:

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
```

At the very top of the document. Hope this isn't to late to help you.

Answer (score 1):

What a mind altering experience that was! For me, it came down to which install guide I read.

[This one](http://galleria.io/docs/getting_started/beginners_guide/) gave me the fatal error msg and all my trial changes as I surfed a resolution.

[This one](http://support.galleria.io/kb/getting-started/beginners-guide) got me back up and running. I took the below HTML and updated my file to look like this version with CSS entries. It worked first go.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="galleria/galleria-1.2.7.min.js"></script>
        <style>
            #galleria{ width: 700px; height: 400px; background: #000; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="galleria">
            <img src="photo1.jpg">
            <img src="photo2.jpg">
            <img src="photo3.jpg">
        </div>
        <script>
            Galleria.loadTheme('galleria/themes/classic/galleria.classic.min.js');
            Galleria.run("#galleria");
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes, the beginner's guide that is linked in the http://galleria.io/download/ page seems to display an example that don't work. After I modifed the code like you mentioned, it works correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You may set `height` and `width` of the element before you call `galleria.run('#galleria');`.
I had the same problem and this fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by opening the javascript file galleria-1.2.7.js and setting debug to false.

Around line 25

```
VERSION = 1.27,
DEBUG = false,
TIMEOUT = 50000,
```

Comment: Or just add it as an option and maintain forward compatibility.